# How to get list of installed app that can sends notification in android?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I am developing an app in which i have to get list of apps which sends notifications in android. I searched a lot but didn't find any solution. So please let me know how do i get list of apps which sends notification.

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of apps you can do it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> appList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent , 0);
```

Then to check if it has notification you can use this but I'm not sure how to use it for the app list.

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled();
```